# Confusion Matrix for Deep Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, confusion-matrix

I have been trying to print out the confusion matrix for my model but failed to do so.

However, I successfully obtained a (7x7) confusion matrix but in tensor format.

I am new to Tensorflow so please help me with displaying the tensor. Thank you.

**code:**

```
con_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], predictions=correct, num_classes=n_classes,
                              dtype=tf.int32, name=None)
with tf.Session():
    print('Confusion Matrix: \n\n', tf.Tensor.eval(con_mat, feed_dict=None, session=None))
```

**output:**

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,100,88] has negative dimensions
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,100,88], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: this is not how you run things in TF. it should be: `with tf.Session() as sess: print(sess.run(con_mat))` (there are other errors too, but lest start with basics; in particular - error is related to placeholder - where do you use placeholders in your code?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not feeding the input placeholder value to calculate the `tensor` correct.

```
feeddict = {your_placeholder: value}
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('Confusion Matrix: \n\n', tf.Tensor.eval(con_mat, feed_dict=feeddict, session=sess))
```

Comment: so in my case, feeddict should be {y: correct}? while y is the placeholder for labels.. @Ishant Mrinal

Comment: I got this error as correct is in tensor format:

`raise TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. '
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.` @Ishant Mrinal , what should I do?

Comment: your feed value should be numpy array, not tensor

Comment: Because the tf.confusion matrix function is in tensor format. In this case, what can i do to convert it to numpy array then? @Ishant Mrinal

Comment: here you can define `correct` as placeholder, and then feed `numpy array` to correct placeholder.  `correct = tf.placeholder(...); feed_dict={correct: numpy_array}`